# Are there MVC/JPA tutorials without using Spring?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, jpa, spring-mvc

this is my first post here.
I am searching for some examples or tutorials for web application using JPA and MVC. All the tutorials and examples that I found so far are related using Spring. I am new on using JPA/MVC and I am finding a little difficult to understand how Spring works. Can anyone recommend me a good tutorial or a simple example without Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what's it worth, the concept 'clicked' for me [through this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594118). A bit dated now, but the basics stay the same. Other than that you can just as well find a bunch of simple tutorials and presentation if you search for something like '[java servlets basic mvc tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20servlets%20basic%20mvc%20tutorial&aq=f&oq=java%20servlets%20basic%20mvc%20tutorial&aqs=chrome.0.57j0.13917&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)'

Comment: the book seems to be very good but do you know any place where I can get it free? if you have it please send it to me: baxhuli@gmail.com

Comment: I did see that you can get the used one for a penny (plus shipping). I don't think I have it anymore though. If you're in the US you can get through an inter-library loan. Also, you can probably get the example source code from Apress

Comment: no I am from East Europe and shipping costs are high. However thank you for your time and responses :)

Answer (score 0):

Watch this videos its easy to understand : http://m.youtube.com/user/koushks?gl=US&hl=en&client=mv-google